# Double title of chart in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, highcharts, html2canvas

Html2canvas is really cool but:

[image]

The function is "simple":

```
$scope.generateScreenshot = function () {
    html2canvas($("#screen-shot"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.open(myImage);
        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas why there is an issue with rendering title ?

Comment: Can you set up a live example or share the full code which allows to reproduce it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is old, awful policy code in Angular 1.2.x...if I will spend on it 3 days without result I will try...